# A general question on positive integer sequence of a certain formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $A=\{\ $ a certain polynomial | all variables$\ \in\mathbb N\ \},\ A\ \subseteq\ \mathbb Z^+,\ $ such as  $A = \{2n−1\ |\ n\in\mathbb N\}$.
Let $B=\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}-A$.
Let $C$ be the set that contians infinite consecutive integers start from some integer n.
Define $\ 2A= \{a+b : a \in A,\ b \in A\}$.
Define $\ 2B=\{a+b : a \in B,\ b \in B\}$.

Suppose the polynomial for $A$ have two variables, both degree is one, what's the simplest form of the polynomial for $A$ that $\ C \ \subseteq\ 2B$ and $\ C \ \nsubseteq\ 2A$?

Comment: If $A$ is linear, then $A$ contains arithmetic progressions, and so does $2A$. If $A$ has degree 2 or more, then $B$ has density 1, and surely that's enough to get arithmetic progressions in $2B$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If $A$ has degree $2$ , is $d$ equals $1$?

Comment: Could be. Why don't you try to prove it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Let $A=\{\ xy\ |\ x,y \in \mathbb N_{\ge 2}\},\ $ it seems $\ \{n,\ n+1k ,\ n+2k, \ ...\}\ \nsubseteq\ 2B$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice you were allowing polynomials in more than one variable. But, wait, you've changed the problem completely when you edited it, turning my first comment into an irrelevance. Why would you do that?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Sorry for my edit.As you commented, this question has many problems,I try to revise this question more reasonable.

Comment: Once a question has mathematical content in the comments, it's generally better to post a new question than to edit the old one in such a damaging way.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your advice.